# Partition numpy array in-place by condition

Tags: python, numpy, bit-manipulation, partitioning, in-place

I have a 1d array of u64 ints. I need to partition it based on given bit inplace.

In pure python it's easy two pointer problem (similar to partitioning in quicksort), but I wonder if it possible to do it efficiently using numpy.

Lets say I have:

```py
arr = np.arange(720, dtype=np.uint64)  # a lot of 64bit unsigned ints
np.random.shuffle(arr)  # in unknown order
left = arr[arr & 32 == 0]  # all elements having 5th bit 0 in any order
right = arr[arr & 32 == 32]  # all elements having 5th bit 1 in any order
arr[:] = np.concatenate([left, right])
```

I would also need to know the index of the partition (aka. `len(left)` above).

Comment: The `arr[:] = ` copy doesn't do much for you.  Since `left` and `right` are copies (boolean indexing), you could copy them to `arr` without the `concatenate`, `arr[:len(left)] = left`, etc.  But I'm not sure that's any more efficient (memory or time).

Comment: I removed your disclaimer: it adds absolutely nothing to the question. That being said, nice question.

Comment: @hpaulj I skipped some context. I do `arr[:] = ...` to keep the same buffer. I use other views of it. This was made to point out that I actually desire in-place modification or `arr` as mentioned in the title. Anyways, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of cool solutions from the community (thank you all!) but looks like it is not possible to stay within O(1) space using pure numpy.

I decided to implement own partition routine and use numba jit to get closer to numpy performance.

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def partition_by_bit(nparr, bit_to_partition_on):
    n = nparr.shape[0]
    i = 0
    j = n - 1
    mask = 1 << bit_to_partition_on

    while True:
        while i < n and (nparr[i] & mask == 0):
            i += 1
        while j >= 0 and (nparr[j] & mask == mask):
            j -= 1
        if i >= j:
            break
        nparr[i], nparr[j] = nparr[j], nparr[i]

    return i

arr = np.arange(720, dtype=np.uint64)
np.random.shuffle(arr)

partition_index = partition_by_bit(arr, 5)  # O(1) space, O(n) time
```

Comment: Neat. While I'm not a big fan of numba in general, this is so simple that it shouldn't cause any problems

Answer (score 2):

You could use argsort to assign the array with the reordered indexes (I'm using the last bit instead of &32 to make the result easier to understand with evens/odds):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(20)  # a lot of 64bit unsigned ints
np.random.shuffle(arr)  # in unknown order

print(arr)
# [ 2  6 15 10 12  5 11  0 14 18 19  3  7  4  1 17  9  8 16 13]
arr[:] = arr[np.argsort(arr&1)]
print(arr)
# [ 2  8  4 16 14  0 18 12 10  6  5 19  3  7 15  1 17  9 11 13]
```

Without sorting, you could setup a mask of the left and right positions, measure the size of the left partition by counting the `True` values in the mask, then assign subscripts with the masked and inverse mask parts.

```
mask = arr&1 == 0
left = np.sum(mask)
arr[:left],arr[left:] = arr[mask],arr[~mask].copy()
```

*note that you have to use .copy() for the second part because the content of arr will have changed before the second assignment takes place.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.argsort`:

```
result = arr[np.argsort(arr & 32)]
```

Sorting `arr & 32` is sorting two values: 0 and 32, which is the partitioning you require. If you need the partition index,

```
(result & 32).argmax()
```

That will return the first index of the maximum value of the array, which is the number of zeros in the sorted data.